# what does the the dword operand do in assembly

Tags: assembly, x86, opcode

hello I am trying to pick up assembly on intel32,

my full question is, what does this mean?

```
mov dword ptr [esp+18h], 0AH
```

I especially do not get the part at [esp+18h]

Comment: Did you consider looking up the documentation?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because the OP has made zero research effort.

Comment: @I found my answer from reading through the documentation at http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/processors/architectures-software-developer-manuals.html?iid=tech_vt_tech+64-32_manuals
I doubt it is something most people would be interested to go through

Comment: The question is whether *you* were prepared to go through it. Glad to see you finally did. It only means one thing: double word.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Brackets in `[ESP+18h]` mean that the destination of the `MOV` is memory location at ESP+18h. As an example, if ESP has value 10000000h, then your destination is memory location 10000018h.

`DWORD` defines 'size' of the memory location used for move operation. In you example, you'd be moving 0000000Ah (4 bytes) into memory location ESP+18h. As `0Ah` is immediate value its size cannot be determined without using `DWORD`, `WORD`, `BYTE` or other similar qualifier.

Intel convention is to define the 'size' of the destination memory location instead of the immediate itself (e.g. `MOV DWORD PTR [ESP+18h], 0Ah` vs `MOV [ESP+18h], dword 0Ah`).

Answer (score 7):

It means store the doubleword (4 bytes on x86) value `0AH` (same as `0000000AH`) in memory at address `esp+18h`. For example, if `esp` contains the value `4` and the memory contents look like:

```
Address      Contents
-----------------------------------------------------
0000: 00 01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 09 0A 0B 0C 0D 0E 0F
0010: 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 1A 1B 1C 1D 1E 1F
```

The after `mov dword ptr [esp+18h], 0AH` you would have:

```
Address      Contents
-----------------------------------------------------
0000: 00 01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 09 0A 0B 0C 0D 0E 0F
0010: 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 1A 1B 0A 00 00 00
```

---

Just writing `mov [esp+18h], 0AH` would be ambigous since the size of the immediate (`0AH`) can't be deduced from the instruction. Hence `dword ptr` is added to tell the assembler that the memory operand is a `dword` and that the immediate therefore also should be a `dword`.

Answer (score 2):

This is likely referring to a memory location that is being used as a variable location. The [esp+18h] is a reference like  a pointer (*) in C. ESP stands for the Extended Stack Pointer. The ESP register contains an address to a memory table where values are stored. You take the value is ESP and add 18h offset to find the final location of the memory address where you want to store the value 0AH.